# PlayFab Custom Server Integration

Tags: networking, server

I want to use PlayFab to host and manage my server instances but I'm unclear on how to implement the requirements [they listed here](https://support.playfab.com/support/discussions/topics/1000040625). My server SDK is in .Net and I'm hoping I can fulfill all the requirements with plugins written in C#. How can I and make parameters available in the command line input? Am I supposed to return information by printing on the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their service would call your server executable (if it was called server.exe) like below

> server.exe -game_id= -game_build_version= -game_mode= -server_host_domain= -server_host_port= -server_host_region= -playfab_api_endpoint= -title_secret_key= -custom_data= -log_file_path= -output_files_directory_path= -batchmode

When they say,

> In designing your server, the following parameters will be available as part of your command line input:
> ... command switches ...

They're actually letting you know that these are the command line switches that will be provided to your server executable when their service calls it to start a new server instance. You would be responsible for reading all these switches in your server program and then parsing their value to do what they describe in their documentation.

For example,

> log_file_path - a string value for the directory where the server log file must be written, so that it can be collected by the PlayFab service upon completion of the instance

You would have to read that switch into a variable and write your logs to that file otherwise their service won't be able to handle the logs you generate properly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying! There're a few more things I'm unsure about. How would I configure my server so PlayFab can access those variables? Also, how would I integrate the MatchMaker API? I'm just not sure how to make my server communicate with PlayFab. Once again, thanks for the information.

Comment: It looks like they have SDKs which you can integrate into your application (https://playfab.com/sdks) and make API calls. They also say (https://api.playfab.com/Documentation) "If you prefer not to use our available SDKs, you can access the entire PlayFab service directly via these REST-like Web APIs." So you'd be making those type of calls to their service to update it.